# Confused about python imports

Tags: python, linux, package, importerror

I reviewed [the Python 2.7.5 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). I am having issues with my real project, but created a small test project here to concisely reproduce the issue. Imagine a package with the following layout stored at ~/Development/Test

Here is the structure:

```
Test/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    sub/
        __init__.py
        test_foo.py
```

And the code (`__init__.py` files are empy):

**foo.py**

```
def bar():
    print("hello world")
```

**test_foo.py**

```
import Test.foo
# also tried from Test import foo

def main():
    foo.bar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When trying to run `test_foo.py` from the terminal (i.e. `python test_foo.py`) I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Test.foo
ImportError: No module named Test.foo
```

I'm trying to import the main file in the package (foo.py) from the test file in the sub module (in my real project the sub module is the unit testing code). Oddly using [Sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) editor and the plugin [python test runner](https://github.com/lyapun/sublime-text-2-python-test-runner), I can run my individual tests just fine, but I cannot build the test file. It gives me the above error.

Comment: There is a typo in your error message: `import foo`, your file code states `import test.foo`

Comment: @kroolik, That was a mistake, should say: Test.foo, I've fixed it.

Comment: You shouldn't create and run scripts that are placed inside your module. Scripts should always be outside the module.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, not sure why you mean by "scripts" but I guess it does make sense to put the unit tests outside of the module. I'm used to structuring things in C#. I was treating the package as a "solution" with projects (in this case the main package and the sub package for testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module names are case-sensitive. Use:

```
import Test.foo as foo
```

(The `as foo` is so that you can call `foo.bar` in `main`.)

---

You must also have `~/Development` listed in PYTHONPATH.

If using Unix and your login shell is bash, to add `~/Development` to `PYTHONPATH` edit ~/.profile to include

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/Development
```

Here are [instructions for Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#configuring-python).

---

Further suggestions for debugging:

Place

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import Test
print(Test)
import Test.foo
```

at the top of `test_foo.py`. Please post the output.

Comment: I've changed the case (same issue). Also used the `as foo` clause and that didn't fix the problem either get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Test.foo as foo
ImportError: No module named Test.foo`

Comment: It sounds like `~/Development` is not listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. You must add that directory so Python will know where to look to import `Test`.

Comment: I'm on linux and added your updated answer to my `~/.profile`, but it still doesn't work, even after reloading bash (i.e. `$ . ~/.profile`). However, when I move test_foo.py outside of the `Test` module (into ~/Development) it now works (if I move it one more level up to ~/, it does not).

Comment: Also, if I remove the PYTHONPATH code from ~/.profile, I have the same results, runs if in ~/Development, but not ~/ or ~/Development/Test/sub

Comment: I've added a suggestion above so we can see some debugging output. The output will clarify (1) if `~/Development` is in your PYTHONPATH and (2) if some other module named `Test` is getting imported before your desired `~/Development/Test` directory.

Comment: ['/home/xxxxx/Development/Test/sub', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/home/xxxxx/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info'] (It isn't adding the path, the first path to ../Test/sub is just the local running dir).

Comment: Also: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Test
ImportError: No module named Test`

Comment: Well, there you go. `~/Development` is not in your PYTHONPATH. I'm not sure why adding `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Development
export PYTHONPATH` to ~/.profile and reloading it with `. ~/.profile` did not work however. Perhaps try logging out and then back in?...

Comment: I updated your answer to use the correct PYTHONPATH syntax to add to .profile or .bashrc (you had incorrectly PATH). You deserve the answer and upvote for your help though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Runnable scripts should always be put outside the module. So if you have a module and a script that runs some code from that module, the structure should look like:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
your_script.py
```

And the code in `your_script.py` should be something like:

```
from foo.bar import your_func

your_func()
```

In case of unittesting it *is* a good idea (this is opinionated and everyone has his way of doing things) to place the tests inside the module so the structure should look like:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    tests/
        test_bar.py
```

But in that case you shouldn't run the script directly. You should either use one of the testing frameworks like `nose` and run:

```
nosetests foo
```

in the directory where you placed your `foo` module.

Or if you used the standard `unittest` library, create a `TestSuite` and what not, run it with:

```
python -m unittest foo.tests.test_bar
```

again in the directory where you placed your foo module.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I am using `nose.` I just added the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part to `test_foo.py` just to reproduce the ImportError, in my actual test file, this is not present. This is my first major python project so having a better understanding of how to structure the directories, files, and runnable scripts is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using nose then the layout you're created is correct, you just have to run the `nosetests` script from outside the project, in the same directory where your `Test` folder is, and run it with `nosetests Test`, or whatever you want to test, `nose` is pretty flexible.